# Prove differentiability of $\sin(z)$ with use of $\phi(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that $\sin(z)$ is differentiable in $a$ with the use of a function $\phi$, that satisfies $\sin(z) = \sin(a) + (z-a)\dot\phi(z)$ and $\phi$ is continuous at $a$. I need to show this by useing powerseries. A hint given is that $\sin(z) = \sin(a + z - a)$

It is clear that $\phi(z) = \cos(z)$, but I'm having trouble showing this with powerseries.

All help is much appreciated

Comment: $\phi(z) = \frac{\sin(z)-\sin(a)}{z-a}$. What is your definition of $\sin(z)$ ?

Comment: $\sin(z) = \sum{(-1)^{n} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$

Comment: $(z-a)\phi(z)=\sin(z)-\sin(a)$ is analytic and $\phi(z)$ is continuous at $z=a$ since $\lim_{z \to a} \phi(z) = \sum{(-1)^{n} \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$ (this is what you need to prove) which means $\phi(z)$ is analytic

Comment: @user1952009 This means the hint doesn't have to be used?

Comment: @user1952009 No I got that the limit goes to $\sum{(-1)^{n}\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$

Comment: Yes of course I meant $\lim_{z \to a} \frac{\sin(z)-\sin(a)}{z-a}=\sum{(-1)^{n} \frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$ ($=\sin'(a) = \cos(a)$). So what do you want more ?

Comment: What trouble exactly? ... BTW "power series" is 2 words.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No help needed, this question has already been answered by reuns

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with power series, not even with the exact definition of sine. It's just the definition of derivative. From your assumptions we get that
$${\sin z-\sin a\over z-a}=\phi(z)\qquad(z\ne a)\ .$$
This implies
$$\lim_{z\to a}{\sin z-\sin a\over z-a}=\lim_{z\to a}\phi(z)=\phi(a)$$
and shows that $\sin'(a)=\phi(a)$.